# Valor inusual de PHP al validar una variable

Tags: php, variables, condiciones

Tengo este código:

```
// Recogemos la variable proceso de la url
$clave = (int)$_POST["clave"];
var_dump($clave);

if ($clave == "sbe9U8%9")
{
    echo "correcto.";
}
else
{
    echo "incorrecto.";
}
```

Tenía un error, inicializaba $clave a entero, por lo tanto siempre era 0, ya que se pedía un valor alfanumérico.

¿Cómo es posible que el código pinte correcto?

Esto es lo que devuelve:

*int(0) correcto.*

Me he quedado muy pillado.

Ya funciona con unos cambios, **pero el resultado anterior no debería de ser aceptado (int)0 nunca puede ser == a (string)"sbe9U8%9"**

Cambios realizados:
$clave = (int)$_POST["clave"];
$clave = (string)$_POST["clave"];

if ($clave == "sbe9U8%9")
if ($clave === "sbe9U8%9")

Comment: puede ser porque comparas cadenas y la comparacion fuerza a la cadena a ser entero

Comment: Te cambio 8 líneas de código por 2, usando un ternario: **`$status=( $clave === "sbe9U8%9" ) ? "correcto" : "incorrecto";  echo $status;`** Puede ser incluso en una línea, pero me gusta guardar todo en variables. Saludos.

Comment: Tienes razón, pero no me acostumbro, me resulta más cómodo a la hora de depurar ver el código así por líneas, eso sí, no sé si el rendimiento variará mucho.

Comment: El rendimiento sería prácticamente el mismo. Ahora bien, si aprendes a usar los ternarios tendrás un código mucho más fácil de depurar, estamos hablando para este caso solamente de 6 líneas de código menos. Un ternario no es un obstáculo a la comprensión del código, te da esa impresión porque no estás familiarizado con ese concepto. Te lo aseguro, si aprendes a usarlos te simplificará muchísimo la programación.

Answer (score 1):

Pues sí, al ser tipos distintos PHP fuerza el segundo valor a entero, al convertir la cadena es 0:

*Si se compara un número con un string o la comparación implica strings numéricos, entonces cada string es convertido en un número y la comparación realizada numéricamente. Estas reglas también se aplican a la sentencia switch. La conversión de tipo no tiene lugar cuando la comparación es === o !== ya que esto involucra comparar el tipo así como el valor.*

Pues este fallo tonto me pudo costar un disgusto!!
Vo a coger como costumbre el cambiar el == por el === ya que siempre inicializo todas las variables.

Comment: estaba escribiendo un comentario y justo has publicado la solucion :)